# Can't simply loop through a list to match passwords (c# winform)

Tags: c#

I've been working on a basic ATM-like application for my Intro to Programming course at my High School. I am trying to match a list of pre-existing "PIN codes" so that a user adding themselves to the database cannot use the same PIN as an existing user, but the following code is always resulting in a 'false' output.

```
        newName01 = txtFirstName.Text;
        newName02 = txtLastName.Text;
        newPin = Convert.ToInt32(txtCreatePin.Text);
        confirmPin = Convert.ToInt32(txtConfirmPin.Text);
        float E = float.Parse(txtDepositInt.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);

        for (var i = 0; i < lstinfo.Count; i++)
        {
            if(newPin == lstinfo[i].pin)
            {
                active = false;
            }
            else
            {
                active = true;
            }
        }

        if(active == true)
        {
            lstinfo.Add(new AccountInfo(newName01, newName02, newPin, E));
            Submit_info();
        }
```

Comment: You're looping through all the pins without ever breaking, so you're only ever getting the result of the last comparison. You should add a `break;` where you set `active = false;`

Comment: put break; in the else after you set active to true. It will force the for-loop to stop.

Comment: Why does a PIN/password need to be unique rather than the username/ID?

Comment: Since this is a learning exercise, I'll add a code review note: don't use `int.Parse` on a PIN because it will remove leading zeroes.  Each digit is significant as a character so operate on the string.  That is, "123" will match "0123" and "00123", etc. if you try to treat the PIN as a number.

Comment: And as an extension to @WelcomeOverflow's question, if you reject a PIN because it's already used by *another account*, your user can now test that PIN against other accounts they might know or come to know in the future (based on patterns or watching someone else type in a user name) and possibly gain access to another user's account.

Comment: To answer @WelcomeOverflow and madreflection's questions - this is a very primitive piece of technology right now... realistically, I based the interface of the ATM off of a real-life one, where instead of a userID you would just use your ATM card.. too late into the programming process (I was basing this off of a similar console app i wrote) did I realize the problem of not having user IDs, and was just using the PINs as an identifier. TL/DR: I forgot to implement userIDs... and don't want to change it in its current state.

Comment: As a pure comment:  Lots of folks taking programming courses post questions to this site (most of whom, I'm assuming, are in post-secondary classes).  Most of them don't post as well structured questions as you did.  You introduced it as a homework issue, you presented your work, you asked a clear question.

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks - try telling that to the user who downvoted lol

Comment: So when trying to register on your ATM, if my pin choice is rejected, I now have access to that account since there is nothing else required like knowing a *matching* name/ID.  Unlike an ATM card, a PIN entry is not a physical thing that only one person can own.  Sounds like a good reason to start over.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow I'm well aware of the real-world limitations of the software - but there's no real value to restarting as there's no real purpose of the software other than a Proof of Concept of what's happening in our Intro course to display at our open house.. keep in mind I've been programming a total of about half a semester. While I very well could add a list of UserIDs... I'm trying to keep user complexity low so that passerbys at the table can easily and quickly toy around with the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through all the pins without ever breaking, so you're only ever getting the result of the last comparison. You should add a `break;` where you set `active = false;`

Instead, set active to `true` initially, then loop through your items. If you find a match, set active to `false` and exit the loop.

Here's an example using your code above:

```
active = true;

// Set active to false if we find a match (and exit the loop at that point)
for (var i = 0; i < lstinfo.Count; i++)
{
    if (newPin == lstinfo[i].pin)
    {
        active = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

But with a `List` of objects the `System.Linq` extension method `Any`, the code can be made even simpler:

```
bool active = !lstinfo.Any(item => item.pin == newPin);
```

---

You mentioned in the comments that this wasn't working, so I guess you'll need to provide some sample data and the code you're using to show what's happening (edit your original question above).

Here's a code sample that shows how this method could be used:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Pin { get; set; }
    public Account(string pin) { Pin = pin; }
}

static void Main()
{
    // Sample data of existing account pins
    var accounts = new List<Account>
    {
        new Account("12345"),
        new Account("40597"),
        new Account("30894"),
        new Account("30498"),
        new Account("02467")
    };

    // Get new pin from user
    string newPin;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a numeric pin: ");
        newPin = Console.ReadLine();

        // Ensure the string is all numbers
        if (!newPin.All(char.IsNumber))
        {
            WriteColorLine("Error - must be numeric digits only\n", ConsoleColor.Red);
            continue;
        }

        // Ensure that the pin is unique
        if (accounts.Any(account => account.Pin == newPin))
        {
            WriteColorLine("Error - pin already exists\n", ConsoleColor.Red);
            continue;
        }

        // If we got this far, the pin is all numbers and
        // doesn't exist so we can break out of the loop
        break;
    }

    // Create new account
    var userAccount = new Account(newPin);
    accounts.Add(userAccount);

    WriteColorLine("\nCongratulations, you have a new pin", ConsoleColor.Green);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: So it still isn't working. I have this setup, followed by the same "if (active == true)" yet it still defaults to being false, with either the for loop or the Any method.

Comment: If active is false then there is a match. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample application that shows how it could be used. Let me know if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Rufus L is right, you need to break if you find the pin is used by someone else, you can use LINQ to get a shorter version of this, try this instead:

```
if(lstinfo.Any(p => p.pin == newPin))
{
    return;
}

lstinfo.Add(new AccountInfo(newName01, newName02, newPin, E));
Submit_info();
```

This way you only will be adding new accounts if the pin is new.